# Understanding type of mips binary

Tags: mips, mips32

I tried `file binary` and would like some help in understanding the output of this.
Outputs are as follows:

ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

and for another file

ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped

I am particularly interested in what `MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV)` and `MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV)` mean and how it related to my mips processor version and mips toolchain version

Comment: `SYSV` is short for System V, which means that the program uses the [System V Application Binary Interface](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIPS-I and MIPS32 version 1 are various iterations of [the MIPS instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Versions_of_the_MIPS_instruction_set).  Generally newer versions of the instruction set are backwards compatible with older versions, so your .so and executable should be compatible.